# Funcanimation works like time.sleep() to run repeatedly functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

this is my question: if I get a code with a funcAnimation implementation (financial field, grabbing data from a exchange and live plot every interval of time)..how can I run a function every interval in a optimise manner?

Imagine we have this code as example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(-6, 6)
tmax = 1
tmin = -1
t = np.linspace(-1, 1)

def f(x, t):
   term = (np.exp(-1*(x-3*t)**2))*np.sin(3*np.pi*(x-t))
   return term

y = f(x, tmax)
lines = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], -1, 1])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f')

counter = [0]
def animate(ts):
   y = f(x, ts)
   lines[0].set_ydata(y)
   plt.legend(['ts=%4.2f' % ts])
   #plt.savefig('tmp_%04d.png' % counter)
   counter[0] += 1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=t, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

In this case that maybe is so simple, when I run it the code get stuck to the close loop cause by funcAnimation.

What I do? put the function to run inside animate function. But...that is a good way to proceed?

Here we have a portion of my code and one simple example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,18),facecolor="#232a3b")

def animate(i):
    say(5)
graphData('BTC/USDT','1m',8,13,21)

def say(i):
    print('Hello World ' + str(i))

while True:
    #pair = input('Crypto pair to plot: ')
    #timeframe = input('Enter timeframe: ')
    say(5)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=60000)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "get stuck to the close loop cause by funcAnimation" mean? I do have severe problems understanding the issue.

Comment: Sorry, my fault...I mean that when I call animation.FuncAnimation inside while True (second example) the code never back again to say(5). So say(5) call only is called one time at the beginning of the process and never again. Because the script is running ani again and again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Mhh, one thing to note is that creating several `FuncAnimations` in a loop is surely not helpful and will in most cases fail. Concerning your problem, I'm still unsure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to grab data periodically in time, manage that data for doing some operations and then graph the data. It is for a trading bot and I want a visual live image of what is doing the bot. So I don´t know if it is a good idea to grab the data and run another functions in order to do trades inside "animate" function (example 2). The code is working really good just graphing live data each 1 minute. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest